# Angular 1.x - set text based on flag without a function

Tags: angularjs

I want to set a text based on a flag. I know I can run a simple function to determine the needed value, but I was wondering if there's a way to put this functionality in the HTML, something as follows:

```
<span>{{someFlag? 'the first text' : 'the second text'}}</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example works, but it is better using `ngBind` directive

```
<span ng-bind="someFlag ? 'the first text' : 'the second text'"></span>
```